# Iterate through Java List

Tags: java, list, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a Spring MVC Web Application

I have a `List` that I populate using

```
List items = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
```

Now, it looks like this when I print it in the `View` using `JSTL`:

```
[{id=1, name=John, status=1}, {id=2, name=Smith, status=1}]
```

Again, in `JSTL` I can iterate through it like this:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${items}">
    ${item.id}, ${item.name}, ${item.status}
</c:forEach>
```

I want to do the same in a `Controller` in order to get just the `id`

```
List list = "";

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    list += items.get(i) + ",";
}
```

But how to get just the id from the cell ?

Comment: Use generic types, not raw types. You should have a List<Something>, not a List. Read the javadoc of the methods you're using: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-. It returns a `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

Comment: @JBNizet Perhaps that should be an answer instead.

Comment: @4castle I'm hoping the OP figures out the solution by him/herself, and learns how important it is to read the javadoc, rather than spoon-feeding him/her with the solution.

Comment: @JBNizet Absolutely, I'm just saying you could copy that comment verbatim into an answer, and I would consider it to be a complete enough answer.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't really qualify as an answer, as it's just a hint and two advices, rather than a real answer explaining how to iteratr on the list and get the ID of each element. Feel free to post it if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing this:

```
List items = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
```

which means, you are declaring a List as a **raw** data holder (btw that is a bad practice)

if you do instead something like

```
List<Map<String, Object>> items = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
```

then you could easily do something like

```
List<Map<String, Object>> myFooList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    for (Map<String, Object> map : myFooList) {
        // your index here like foo.getId()
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more like `map.get("id")`? It's not actually returning their objects, just a `ResultSet`-like `List` with table column names for the keys.

Comment: With the additional comment, worked like a charm! Thanks to both of you :)